# LINQ comparing string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

**Question:** I want to use LINQ and check if one of the `CarNames` is inside `result1`. Why `result1` returns nothing but `result2` works fine?

`result2` returns nothing

```
IQueryable<Cars_Model> Query = await _services.GetAllCars();
string result1 = "Car,Truck,Van";  
Query = Query.Where(x => x.CarsName.ToUpper().Contains(result1.ToUpper()));
```

`result2` works fine

```
      IQueryable<Cars_Model> Query = await _services.GetAllCars();
      string result2 = "Car";  // this works fine 
      Query = Query.Where(x => x.CarsName.ToUpper().Contains(result2.ToUpper()));
```

other information

```
public class Cars_Model
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    
    public string CarsName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a few examples of `x.CarsName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just judging by your data I *think* you intended to do this instead:

```
IQueryable<Cars_Model> Query = await _services.GetAllCars();
var expectedTypes = "Car,Truck,Van".ToUpper().Split(",");  
Query = Query.Where(x => expectedTypes.Contains(x.CarsName.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: aww you are correct. I though x.CarsName always comes first. but after flipping them its work now.. thank you

Comment: @dave - the order is determined by logic eg. `"AB".Contains("B")` isn’t the same as `"B".Contains("AB")` therefor your statement „I though x.CarsName always comes first“ is illogical